# Pumping lemma -- Is this enough to prove that the language L is not regular?

Tags: pumping-lemma

I have a language $L$:

$$L = \{w :  a^ib^j; i > j \}$$

I need to prove this language is not regular using Pumping Lemma. I'm wondering if I'm doing it correctly:

$L$ Is assumed to be regular. A regular language means that a DFA exists that can produce all the strings in $L$. So I need to find a string that exists in L but cannot be represented by a DFA.

So I need to prove that L is not regular by finding a counter example,

I need to find a suitable $w$, where $|w| \geq p$ (the pumping length). I choose:

$$w = a^{(p + 1)}b^p$$

This string can be broken up into $3$ substrings ($x, y$ and $z$), where $|y| > 0$.

$k = 2$:

$$xy^2z = a^{(p + 1)}b^{(p + |y|)}$$

Since $p + 1$ is not greater than $p + |y|$, then $L$ is not a regular language.

Would this be enough to prove that the language is not regular? Here, I assumed that $|y|$ could be $1$, since the number of $a$'s is a minimum of $1$.

Comment: How are you pumping b's? $|xy| \le 2$, so $x$ and $y$ should consist strictly of a's.

Comment: Hint: This is one of those cases in which it is useful to pump *down*.

Comment: @dkaeae sorry i'm not sure what you mean. If I pump down, do you mean that I have to do something like: $xy^0z = a^(p+1-|y|)b^p$ ? This would mean that $p+1-|y|$ is at most $p$ right? I'm overall confused as to why I should put $|y|$ in there. I don't even know what the string $y$ actually is. My teacher posted an answer (to a different pumping lemma question) where he uses $|y|$ in there. If you can please explain. Link: https://users.encs.concordia.ca/~grahne/comp335/Q10.pdf